# how to use Jenkins apiToken for build api

Tags: jenkins

Could someone please elaborate on how to use jenkins apiToken for build through rest api.

I want to use user based authentication for Jenkins build.

So I have that apiToken with me but when I am trying to build a job I am getting forbidden exception.

I have followed the below url for build a job.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called Python Jenkins that provides the wrapper around the Jenkins REST API. I believe you may find a sample of using the authenticated build invocation there. You may find it [here](http://packages.python.org/python-jenkins/index.html#api-documentation)